# scroll down button changes url django

Tags: python, html, django, smooth-scrolling

I am working on a django website which contains a button at the top of the page, which when clicked should scroll down. The button is enclosed in an anchor tag, with a specified href attribute.

When I click the button the program alters the url, resulting in a 404 error.

How do I code this to ensure that the url is not affected when the button is clicked?

This is my code so far

```
<a class="scroll_down_button" href='.second_part'>click</a>

<div class="second_part">
    This is a test
</div>
```

This is the error I am getting

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/.second_part
```

Comment: `'.second_part'` is not valid here, you'd better call `<a class="scroll_down_button" href="{% url 'second_part' %}">click</a>` or  `{% url 'YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE:second_part' %}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like that:

```
<a class="scroll_down_button" href="{% url 'second_part' %}">click</a>

<div class="second_part">
    This is a test
</div>
```

Example :

```
<div id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: If I use `{% url 'second_part' %}`, I should also add `second_part` to the `urlpatterns` list right???

Comment: Yes, you have to